# PHP - how to read xml inside object from WS

Tags: php, xml

how do i print (echo) "supplierName" attribute?

I have web service that bring me data

```
global  $s;
global  $params;
$s = new soapclient($conDetails['url'],array('wsdl'));
$params = new stdClass;
$paramsStr = ' 
                <LoginInput>
                    <LoginRec Action="SuppAuthn" UserEmail="'.$email.'" UserPass="'.$password.'" />
                </LoginInput>
            ';
$params->xmlRequest = $paramsStr;

$result = $s->__call("SubmitXmlString",array($params));
```

printed data looks like this:

```
echo "<pre>".(var_dump($result,true))."</pre>";


object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
    ["SubmitXmlStringResult"]=> string(496) 
    "<LoginOutput>
        <Login UsrId="30" UsrName="Some Name" SessionId="10" supplierCode="2" supplierName="Supp name" supplierEmail=""/>
        <Countries>
            <country code="DE" name="Germany"/>
            <country code="ES" name="Spain"/>
            <country code="FR" name="France"/>
        </Countries>
    </LoginOutput>
" } bool(true)
```

how do i print (echo) "supplierName" attribute?

i tried:

```
$xmlString = $result->SubmitXmlStringResult;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo $xml->LoginOutput->Login[0]->attributes()->supplierName;
echo $xml->Login['supplierName'];
```

but it's not working

Comment: Should be `echo $xml->LoginOutput->Login['supplierName'];`

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are accessed with `[]` notation:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo $xml->Login['supplierCode'];  // no need for [0] if `Login` is a single node
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't print anything... :/

Comment: Maybe something to do with the object "above" the xml?